# issue installing NPM packages (tailwaind)

Tags: macos, npm, yarnpkg

I can't install new packages in a new repo with either NPM (v6.13.6) or Yarn (v1.22.4). I've tried an existing repo using `npm install` and it works fine so that's not the issue. I'm on macOS 11.6.7 using zsh trying to install tailwindcss. Running npm install on existing projects seems to work fine.

Comment: What command are you running and what is the error? Does the current working directory have npm or yarn initialized (i.e. `npm init` or `yarn init`)? Is there a `package.json` in the cwd?

Comment: i initialized a package.json via yarn, but both yarn and npm are just sitting there... yarn fails saying no internet connection

Comment: Are you using the default registry? Running `npm config get registry` should print `https://registry.npmjs.org/` if you are.

Comment: im not actually, would rather not share the url here - from a prev company, i cant seem to find a way to chat with you privately, do you know how?

Comment: That's fine, idk how or if there even is a PM on SO. But I think the registry would be the most likely cause, if that is a mirror registry and doesn't have a package or you don't have access that would cause this. One way to check this is set the registry to the default. FYI installing packages in a team where someone has the `registry` set to something which other cannot access can cause the `__.lock` file to point to a bad registry. If you post the error message you are getting in your original post that would help, you can just obfuscate any PII and the registry url.